# Etymology of the adjective ‘idoneus’

Tags: etymology

All etymological dictionaries includung *Wiktionary* and De Vaan’s *Etymological Dictionary* state the ultimate origin of the Latin adjective *idoneus* (‘suitable’; ‘sufficient’) is unknown.

I was wondering if anybody had a theory on the origin of this word; I would be glad if someone could shed light on this problem.

Also, De Vaan says:

> The morphology can be interpreted as an adj. in *-neus* to **idō* (‘there’?) 
>     or **ido-*, or as an adj. in *-eus* to **idōn*.

Answer (score 2):

I randomly just stumbled upon this over a year old question but here's my take on it:

"Idoneus" has just always sounded very Greek to me, although such a word does not exist in Greek; at least not a word that has a similar meaning to it.

But if we take a look at what De Vaan said, it could be an adj. in -eus to "idon", which *does* exist in Greek (participle of εἶδον) and translates roughly to "perceive/see/**be able to see**" (if I'm not mistaken). This doesn't help a lot, but if we look at the origins of εἶδον we get the Sanskrit ancestor "vedyā́", which most likely translates to "knowledge" or "art". With a lot of goodwill this could be semantically at least somewhat close to the Latin "idoneus".

This is just what my gut feeling tells me what could be its etymology. I really don't have any evidence to back up my claim and I know it's kind of far-fetched.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Given how long the question has gone without an answer, any reasonable guess is a welcome contribution.

Comment: εἶδον is from *weid, cognate with Latin video, and cannot be connected with idoneus.